# Map view shows my location and destination but doesn't show directions between them

Tags: ios, mkmapview, clgeocoder, mkplacemark

When I initialize the map, it shows both my location and the destination (forward geocoded from a string) but it does not draw directions between them.

Here is my code :

```
#import "EventDetailMapViewController.h"

@interface EventDetailMapViewController ()
@property (nonatomic,strong) MKMapItem *destination;
@end

@implementation EventDetailMapViewController

CLPlacemark *thePlacemark;
MKRoute *routeDetails;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    _mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;

    _mapView.delegate = self;
    [self getRoute];

}


- (void)addAnnotation:(CLPlacemark *)placemark {
    MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    point.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(placemark.location.coordinate.latitude, placemark.location.coordinate.longitude);
    point.title = [placemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:@"Street"];
    point.subtitle = [placemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:@"City"];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:point];
}



-(void)showRoute:(MKDirectionsResponse *)response{

    for (MKRoute *route in response.routes)
    {
        [_mapView
         addOverlay:route.polyline level:MKOverlayLevelAboveRoads];

        for (MKRouteStep *step in route.steps){
            NSLog(@"%@",step.instructions);
        }



    }

}

-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    // If it's the user location, just return nil.
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;
    // Handle any custom annotations.
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKPointAnnotation class]]) {
        // Try to dequeue an existing pin view first.
        MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView*)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"CustomPinAnnotationView"];
        if (!pinView)
        {
            // If an existing pin view was not available, create one.
            pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"CustomPinAnnotationView"];
            pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
        } else {
            pinView.annotation = annotation;
        }
        return pinView;
    }
    return nil;
}
-(void)getRoute {
    [self getLocationFromString];

    MKDirectionsRequest *directionsRequest = [[MKDirectionsRequest alloc] init];
    MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithPlacemark:thePlacemark];
    [directionsRequest setSource:[MKMapItem mapItemForCurrentLocation]];
    [directionsRequest setDestination:[[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark]];
    directionsRequest.transportType = MKDirectionsTransportTypeAutomobile;
    MKDirections *directions = [[MKDirections alloc] initWithRequest:directionsRequest];
    [directions calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:^(MKDirectionsResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error %@", error.description);
        } else {
            routeDetails = response.routes.lastObject;
            [self.mapView addOverlay:routeDetails.polyline];

        }
    }];
}
-(MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay {
    MKPolylineRenderer  * routeLineRenderer = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithPolyline:routeDetails.polyline];
    routeLineRenderer.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
    routeLineRenderer.lineWidth = 5;
    return routeLineRenderer;
}


- (IBAction)changeMapType:(id)sender {
    if (_mapView.mapType == MKMapTypeStandard)
        _mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
    else
        _mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
}


-(void)getLocationFromString{

    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geocoder geocodeAddressString:self.agendaEntry.address completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        } else {
            thePlacemark = [placemarks lastObject];
            float spanX = 1.00725;
            float spanY = 1.00725;
            MKCoordinateRegion region;
            region.center.latitude = thePlacemark.location.coordinate.latitude;
            region.center.longitude = thePlacemark.location.coordinate.longitude;
            region.span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(spanX, spanY);
            [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
            [self addAnnotation:thePlacemark];
        }
    }];
}

@end
```

I'm relatively new to this so some of this is probably wrong. What I want is when I push a button (in another view) the "agendaEntry" gets passed on the segue. It contains a string with an address, this address gets forward-geocoded and the map displays directions/routes from the user's location to the address in that string.

I don't know how to make it show driving/walking directions or to make it show multiple routes. But for starters, it would be great if it would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it doesn't draw directions is because the directions request is being made *before* the destination placemark (`thePlacemark`) is actually set by the `geocodeAddressString` completion handler block.

Note what the documentation says about `geocodeAddressString:completionHandler:`:

> This method submits the specified location data to the geocoding server asynchronously and returns.

So even though `getLocationFromString` (which calls `geocodeAddressString`) is called before the directions request, execution returns and continues in `getRoute` immediately after the `geocodeAddressString` is initiated (but not completed).

Therefore, `thePlacemark` is still `nil` when `getRoute` sets up `directionsRequest` and you're probably getting an error logged such as "directions not available".

To account for this, you can move the call to the directions-request-set-up code to *inside* the `geocodeAddressString` completion handler block (after the add-annotation code).

There are three things to change for this:

1. In `viewDidLoad`, do `[self getLocationFromString];` *instead of* `[self getRoute];`.
2. In `getRoute`, *remove* the call to `getLocationFromString`.
3. In `getLocationFromString`, in the completion handler block, after `[self addAnnotation:thePlacemark];`, do `[self getRoute];`.

---

Regarding showing multiple routes, first you'll need to actually request alternate routes (default is `NO`):

```
directionsRequest.requestsAlternateRoutes = YES;
```

The other part of the problem you may have experienced is due to this line in `rendererForOverlay`:

```
MKPolylineRenderer  * routeLineRenderer = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] 
    initWithPolyline:routeDetails.polyline];
```

It's creating a polyline renderer using an external instance variable instead of the `overlay` parameter provided to the delegate method.  This basically means the delegate method will only work for that one specific overlay (`routeDetails.polyline`) and since there's no control over when exactly the delegate method will be called by the map view, you can't reliably set `routeDetails.polyline` from outside the delegate method to be sure it points to the right overlay.  Each alternate route is a separate polyline and the map view will make separate calls to `rendererForOverlay` for each one.

Instead, create the polyline renderer using the `overlay` parameter (and first check if `overlay` is an `MKPolyline`):

```
-(MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay {
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolyline class]])
    {
        MKPolylineRenderer  * routeLineRenderer = 
            [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithPolyline:overlay];
        routeLineRenderer.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
        routeLineRenderer.lineWidth = 5;
        return routeLineRenderer;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Then in `getRoute`, instead of this:

```
routeDetails = response.routes.lastObject;
[self.mapView addOverlay:routeDetails.polyline];
```

call the `showRoute` method you already have which adds all the routes:

```
[self showRoute:response];
```

Comment: Additionally: I suggest making `thePlacemark` and `routeDetails` instance variables (declare in the @interface section) instead of global variables which is what they are now.  You actually don't even need `routeDetails` and even `thePlacemark` can be removed and passed as parameters to all the methods.

Comment: The first part i solved myself , but the polylines where giving me trouble. Thanks a lot. Small question : how can i make the call to the network asynchronously, my UI lags a bit when i enter the view , probably because i'm making the call on the main thread.

Comment: Just read that calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler is asynchronous , my phone is lagging ( iph 4 ) , thanks again !.

Comment: Woooaaww! Nice answer @Anna :) +1